# How to generate *.pot file from static HTML file

Tags: internationalization, gettext, xgettext

Is there an easy and straight forward method to generate *.pot file from a static HTML page?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to get it done using Poedit, but was not successful.

Comment: I know it works for C and some other programming languages, but not for HTML. I experimented, to some extent, with xgettext.

Comment: Have you tried [html2po](https://github.com/translate/translate/blob/master/docs/commands/html2po.rst) with the `--pot` flag

Comment: @MichaelWarner No, I was unaware of this tool. Just tried it - and it does what I need it to do. If you convert your comment into an answer, you get the bounty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [html2po](https://github.com/translate/translate/blob/master/docs/commands/html2po.rst) with the `--pot` flag.